# "$.support is undefined"

Tags: jquery, fancybox

"$.support is undefined" error when trying to use fancybox with jQuery. Never seen this before.

Could it be due to conflicting jQuerys? Any ideas?

jQuery is definitely being run, as the other elements on the page that utilize it work fine.

Answer (score 4):

did you make sure that the jquery library is on top of the jquery fancy box library?

see for example this one:

this is wrong

```
<script src="../../FancyBox/Fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this is the right way

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../.. /FancyBox/Fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you including the fancybox JavaScript file **before** jQuery? Don't.

Answer (score 1):

What version of jQuery are you using?
$.support is a feature implemented in jQuery 1.3+

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to the latest jquery version.